# Install SQL Server through command line (for Inno Setup)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, inno-setup

I came here with a problem with were I am working for days, and drives me crazy ... I really appreciate if you guide me into solving this: I have an critical task. To create an Inno setup kit, which should install MS SQL Server, and an app created by us (nothing special). But I noticed that cannot install SQL Server by command line ... and I have tried in a lot of ways ... Here is the last attempt (with no success):

```
SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /INSTANCEID=SQLEXPRESS /QS /HIDECONSOLE /INDICATEPROGRESS='True' /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SQLSVCACCOUNT='NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS='BUILTIN\Administrators' /SKIPRULES='RebootRequiredCheck'
```

The installation is begin, but after few seconds, everything is stop, with apparently no reason, with no message ... and the last message box that I have see is the following:

[image]

I have done something wrong ? Can you help me ? I have tried this on Win10 64bit (I have tried this on Win7 32 bit too), and SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe is SQL Server 2012 32 bit, but 64 bit version behave the same ... no difference.
If I pass trough this task, I guess I can put all in an Inno Setup kit ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation indicates that the **/FEATURES** parameter is required. This specifies what gets installed. So it looks like you aren't telling the installer to install anything.

Taken from the documentation:

Feature parameter examples:

**/FEATURES=SQLEngine** :Installs the Database Engine without replication and full-text.

**/FEATURES=SQLEngine, FullText** :Installs the Database Engine and full-text.

**/FEATURES=SQL, Tools** : Installs the complete Database Engine and all tools.

There are other options. See here for full description https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt#Feature

Comment: I will try what you said and I'll let you know what I have done. Thank you for your response !

Comment: After installation, how can I login with sa user, is there a default password? or should I pass it through command parameter?